# Get dates when quantity were out of stock

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to figure out how to get a date range result when quantity were out of stock with LINQ C#

Lets say I have a table result that looks like this

```
EventDate  | Qty
2014-02-03 | 6
2014-02-04 | -1
2014-02-05 | -2
2014-02-06 | 2
2014-02-07 | -1
2014-02-08 | -2
2014-02-09 | -3
2014-02-10 | 5
```

Now I want to get a date range when qty was minus 0 in stock like this

```
FromDate   | ToDate
2014-02-04 | 2014-02-05
2014-02-07 | 2014-02-09
```

Could someone help me please how to achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I know I can do that with multiplying the query but I would like to do that in just one LINQ query if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard if you break the problem up into small parts. First get the dates where the qty was negative (Linq's `.Where()` function) then pass the results to a custom function where the return type is `List<OutOfStockRange>` and have a class `class OutOfStockRange { public Datetime FromDate {get; set;} public DateTime ToDate {get; set;}}` Your custom function just needs to find the contiguous regions and create a new `OutOfStockRange` and add it to the list to return.

Comment: @mason I'm trying to do that in one linq query, is that possible?

Comment: You can chain the hypothetical custom function into your Linq query. You might be able to avoid doing it with a custom function too, but I'm only good at basic Linq stuff.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). And besides, "thanks in advanced" is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an alternative using only built in functions,

The strategy here is to select all dates where quantity is less than zero, and for each of those dates, do a subquery that builds a list of all the dates after the current date with a quantity also less than zero. Using the `TakeWhile`, this will stop before the next date with a non-negative quantity. The maximum of those is then taken which is correct for the end date of the range. The final step is the `GroupBy` to remove all the days after the start of the "out of stock" range which map to the same end date, to leave you with a distinct range of out of stock date ranges.

As it is below, it relies on the stock levels being sorted in chronological order on input.

```
public class StockLevel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }                        
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<StockLevel> stockLevels = new List<StockLevel>()
    { 
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("03-Feb-2014"), Quantity = 6 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("04-Feb-2014"), Quantity = -1 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("05-Feb-2014"), Quantity = -2 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("06-Feb-2014"), Quantity = 2 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("07-Feb-2014"), Quantity = -1 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("08-Feb-2014"), Quantity = -2 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("09-Feb-2014"), Quantity = -3 },
        new StockLevel() { Date = DateTime.Parse("10-Feb-2014"), Quantity = 5 },
    };

    var outOfStockDates = stockLevels
        .Where(a => a.Quantity < 0)
        .Select(a => new 
        { 
                S1 = a.Date, 
                S2 = stockLevels
                        .Where(c => c.Date >= a.Date)
                        .TakeWhile(b => b.Quantity < 0)
                        .Select(b => b.Date).Max() 
        })
        .GroupBy(a => a.S2, a => a.S1, (S2, S1S) => new { FromDate = S1S.Min(), ToDate = S2 });

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: That seems to be doing the trick, and yes that counts as a single query :), awesome work. Testing it now for my actual code.

Comment: @believeme is there a way that you might have something like this?
`2014-02-03 | 6, 2014-02-03 | 3, 2014-02-03 | -1, 2014-02-03 | -2, 2014-02-03 | 1, 2014-02-03 | -10, 2014-02-03 | -9, 2014-02-03 | 10`? And by this i mean that for a single day you can have different quantities ?

Comment: @alexo Yup, you got it.

Comment: @steve16351 That code is the cleanest and nicest LINQ code I've ever seen :) Thanks

Comment: @believeme yeah, that group by in the end solves the problem then. single issue that i see here is performance wise, because using so much linq its a lot of expression trees generation. Anyway, a very good question and answer

Comment: @alexo Its better then using multiple foreach loops and functions that slows down the application, I think.

Comment: @believeme linq does the same thing, it iterates, and its slower, but more compact. When you are doing a `where` for example, `linq` is going to iterate over the entire collection using an expression tree and it applies the `predicate` you provide. You could do the same thing using a `foreach`, which uses the `Iterator` from the `GetEnumerator`, this is slightly faster, or you could directly use the vanilla `for` or `while` which is index based access, fastest. Anyway, the thing that slows down the processing the most is the memory availability of your CPU.

Comment: @alexo Seems like I'm still a newbie when it comes to performance in C# :), I'm only coding C# for 3 months, believe it or not... Thanks for your lesson anyways

Comment: @believeme, you're welcome. Alexo is right, this will be slower than a non-LINQ alternative. Depends on how much data you have and what performance requirement as to whether that's a problem or not.. I benchmarked on stock levels daily since 2001 (5000 list items), 150ms with this LINQ... 0.8ms with a loop! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom function to change into the Linq expression.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
    {
    public class Class1
        {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            IEnumerable<QuantityDate> quantityDates = GetQuantityDates();//I'm sure you already have some way of retrieving these, via EF or Linq to SQL etc.
            var results = quantityDates.Where(qd => qd.Qty < 0).CombineResults(); //This is the main Linq expression
            foreach (var result in results)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("From Date: {0} To Date: {1}", result.FromDate, result.ToDate);
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }

        //Just to see the data for the moment. You'll probably get this data via EF or Linq to SQL
        public static List<QuantityDate> GetQuantityDates()
            {
            List<QuantityDate> seed = new List<QuantityDate>()
            {
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 3), Qty = 6 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 4), Qty = -1 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 5), Qty = -2 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 6), Qty = 2 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 7), Qty = -1 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 8), Qty = -2 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 9), Qty = -3 },
            new QuantityDate() { EventDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 10), Qty = 5 }
            };
            return seed;
            }
        }
    public static class Extensions
        {

        //This is where the magic happens, and we combine the results
        public static List<OutOfStockRange> CombineResults(this IEnumerable<QuantityDate> input)
            {
            List<OutOfStockRange> output=new List<OutOfStockRange>();
            OutOfStockRange lastEntered = null;
            foreach(var qd in input.OrderBy(qd => qd.EventDate))
             {
                 if(lastEntered != null && lastEntered.ToDate.AddDays(1) == qd.EventDate)
                 {
                     lastEntered.ToDate = qd.EventDate;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lastEntered =new OutOfStockRange(){FromDate = qd.EventDate, ToDate = qd.EventDate};
                     output.Add(lastEntered);
                 }
            }
            return output;
        }
        }

    //This class represents the input data
    public class QuantityDate
        {
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        }

    //This class represents the output data
    public class OutOfStockRange
        {
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

Start with your data:

```
var stockQuantities = new []
{
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 3), Qty = 6 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 4), Qty = -1 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 5), Qty = -2 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 6), Qty = 2 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 7), Qty = -1 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 8), Qty = -2 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 9), Qty = -3 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2014, 2, 10), Qty = 5 },
};
```

Then query for the out of stock records:

```
var outOfStock = stockQuantities.Where(x => x.Qty < 0);
```

Now use `Aggregate` to build the results:

```
var outOfStockRanges =
    outOfStock
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            outOfStock
                .Take(1)
                .Select(x => new { From = x.Date, To = x.Date })
                .ToList(),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                if (a.Last().To.AddDays(1.0) == x.Date)
                    a[a.Count - 1] = new { From = a.Last().From, To = x.Date };
                else
                    a.Add(new { From = x.Date, To = x.Date });
                return a;
            });
```

This is the result I get:

[image: result]

Comment: That is too messy and will not work for my actual code

Comment: @believeme - This is exactly what you asked for in your question. It's using LINQ and it provides the exact output you required. What is too messy about it and what won't work?

Comment: The problem with that is because you're skipping the first row and what if I have more then 1 to skip, and how about the rest?

Comment: @believeme - I'm not actually skipping a row. Inside the `.Aggregate` I'm doing a `.Take(1)` to load the first record into the accumulator. The `.Skip(1)` just jumps over this first record so that it is not processed twice. I don't know what you mean by needing to skip more than one. The `.Where(x => x.Qty < 0)` means I don't need to skip any.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following:

```
var src_objects = new []
{
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-03"), qty = 6},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-04"), qty = -1},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-05"), qty = -2},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06"), qty = 2},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-07"), qty = -1},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-08"), qty = -2},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-09"), qty = -3},
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-10"), qty = 5}
};


int i = 0;


var ranges = src_objects
    .OrderBy(key => key.date)
    .Select(obj =>
    {
        if (obj.qty > 0)
        {
            ++i;
            return new { date = obj.date, group_key = 0 };
        }
        else
            return new { date = obj.date, group_key = i };
    })
    .Where(obj => obj.group_key != 0)
    .GroupBy(obj => obj.group_key)
    .Select(g => new { fromdate = g.First().date, todate = g.Last().date });

ranges
.ToList()
.ForEach(range => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", range.fromdate, range.todate.Date)));
```